# I do not see instrumented code run when using a class that implements an interface affected by ByteBuddy's onMethodEnter

Tags: aop, byte-buddy

Situation detailed below with some pseudocode of sorts.

```java
Class implements Interface {
  method() {}
}
```

and

```java
@Advice.OnMethodEnter()
public static methodEnter(@Advice.Argument(0) final Interface) {
  System.out.println("I don't end up seeing this print message when calling methods from Class")
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be? Mostly looking for a general "this should work" versus "this does not work and I am missing something critical about how ByteBuddy works". I'm looking at some open-source code that seems like a Black Box, that isn't operating as expected, so I'm trying to get a grasp of how AOP works. Learning resources are also appreciated, albeit ByteBuddy seems a bit particular so I haven't been able to find answers from their documentation so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn AOP basics, I suggest you use AspectJ, it is easier to learn and apply than a relatively low-level byte code instrumentation framework like ByteBuddy (BB).

The thing with BB is that you need to set up the instrumentation first, you cannot just write an aspect, compile the code and expect it to work. In order to do that you need to know a few basics about Java instrumentation and, depending on your scenario, also on Java agents. For example, if you want to transform a class which was already loaded, you can only transform it in a way which avoids introducing new methods or fields or changing existing ones with regard to their signature and modifiers. If you add both `byte-buddy` and `byte-buddy-agent` to your classpath, you might want to do something like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62521099;

import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION;
import static net.bytebuddy.implementation.bytecode.assign.Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC;
import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.*;

class ByteBuddyDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    weaveAspect();
    MyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
    myInterface.doSomething();
    System.out.println("7 + 8 = " + myInterface.add(7, 8));
  }

  private static void weaveAspect() {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
      .disableClassFormatChanges()
      .with(RETRANSFORMATION)
      .type(isSubTypeOf(MyInterface.class))
      .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
        builder.visit(
          Advice.to(MyByteBuddyAspect.class).on(isMethod())
        )
      )
      .installOn(instrumentation);
  }

  interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething();

    int add(int a, int b);
  }

  static class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
      System.out.println("Doing something");
    }

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
    }
  }

  static abstract class MyByteBuddyAspect {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void before(
      @Advice.This(typing = DYNAMIC, optional = true) MyInterface target,
      @Advice.Origin Method method,
      @Advice.AllArguments(readOnly = false, typing = DYNAMIC) Object[] args
    )
    {
      System.out.println("MyByteBuddyAspect.before");
      System.out.println("  Method: " + method);
      System.out.println("  Instance: " + target);
      System.out.println("  Arguments: " + Arrays.deepToString(args));
    }
  }
}
```

See? There is quite a lot of boilerplate code here. I do not want to explain all the details, better search the Web for tutorials. The BB web site also has one, even though outdated in some regards. BB is so feature-rich, it can be quite overwhelming.

The console log for my solution above would be:

```
MyByteBuddyAspect.before
  Method: public void de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62521099.ByteBuddyDemo$MyClass.doSomething()
  Instance: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62521099.ByteBuddyDemo$MyClass@61544ae6
  Arguments: []
Doing something
MyByteBuddyAspect.before
  Method: public int de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62521099.ByteBuddyDemo$MyClass.add(int,int)
  Instance: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62521099.ByteBuddyDemo$MyClass@61544ae6
  Arguments: [7, 8]
7 + 8 = 15
```

So there you see how you can access the target instance, the method information (only use if needed, otherwise omit it) and the arguments list.

You can add more options if you want to use a combination of enter/exit advices in order to dynamically decide whether to execute or skip the original method, whether to manipulate the arguments or the result etc. All of this is quite a learning curve, but I recently also went through it. So it is definitely possible. I still much prefer AspectJ for AOP and use BB only for more low-level stuff like creating special types of test doubles (mocks). But that is another story.

Comment: Thank you - this provides a lot of useful context. ByteBuddy is being used within a library in my context, so I will look for where they do the instrumentation installs to see what is being done.

I agree - throughout this research I have basically been wishing I were looking at AspectJ instead :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing elsewhere. Byte Buddy (just like AspectJ by the way) is not built into the Java platform. The aspect (or advice) needs to be attached to The JVM somehow. Byte Buddy (just like AspectJ) offers build-time instrumentation. If you wanted to instrument a class that is part of your project, build-time instrumentation is the easiest.

The build plugin offers out-of-the-box support with Maven and Gradle. You can implement advice by applying it within a `net.bytebuddy.build.Plugin`. Match all classes you want to change and then apply the advice in the builder using `DynamicType.Builder::visit` where you register your `Advice.to(...).on(...)`.

If you want to instrument library code or JVM code, this needs to be done during runtime using a Java agent. Doing so, register an `AgentBuilder` where you more or less apply the same dynamic type builder API.

Comment: Hi Rafael, I am currently reading your "Definitive Guide to Java Agents" and hope it will help me understand this more. My context for ByteBuddy is that it is being used within a framework, and I am assuming the creators of that framework have handled that. I'm going to look into their logic a bit more to try to understand it better. Thank you for the answer! (And the Java agent guide)

Comment: One more bit of information about ByteBuddy vs. AspectJ: While I personally prefer AspectJ for AOP-style programming, sometimes BB trumps AJ, e.g. if you wish to instrument JRE classes during runtime (not build time). With BB you can do that while AJ explicitly ignores `java` and `javax` packages and in general is not designed to be used in an "inline all instrumentation code" mode, whereas you can do that with BB. So with regard to retransforming already loaded classes (not transforming them during build time or during class-loading), BB is more powerful than AJ, even though trickier to use.